# raspberry 3 - lost wlan0 interface

Tags: pi-3, wifi

I've lost wlan0 interface on my Raspberry Pi3 - It was working till today, until (most probably) it restarted because it got disconnected from power for a moment.
I did last dist-update few weeks ago - but there were several restarts days/weeks after that. I don't recall making any software/config changes.

On GUI I get the information that "no wireless interface found"

sudo ifconfig wlan0 up gives:

```
wlan0: ERROR while getting interface flags: No such device
```

uname -a:

```
Linux raspberrypi 4.4.9-v7+ #884 SMP Fri May 6 17:28:59 BST 2016 armv7l GNU/Linux
```

uname -mrs:

```
Linux 4.4.9-v7+ armv7l
```

(altough in /lib/modules I have only two directories: 4.9.35+ and 4.9.35-v7+)

My dmesg:

```
[    0.000000] Booting Linux on physical CPU 0x0
[    0.000000] Initializing cgroup subsys cpuset
[    0.000000] Initializing cgroup subsys cpu
[    0.000000] Initializing cgroup subsys cpuacct
[    0.000000] Linux version 4.4.9-v7+ (dc4@dc4-XPS13-9333) (gcc version 4.9.3 (crosstool-NG crosstool-ng-1.22.0-88-g8460611) ) #884 SMP Fri May 6 17:28:59 BST 2016
[    0.000000] CPU: ARMv7 Processor [410fd034] revision 4 (ARMv7), cr=10c5383d
[    0.000000] CPU: PIPT / VIPT nonaliasing data cache, VIPT aliasing instruction cache
[    0.000000] Machine model: Raspberry Pi 3 Model B Rev 1.2
[    0.000000] cma: Reserved 8 MiB at 0x3a800000
[    0.000000] Memory policy: Data cache writealloc
[    0.000000] On node 0 totalpages: 241664
[    0.000000] free_area_init_node: node 0, pgdat 808c0d80, node_mem_map b9fa6000
[    0.000000]   Normal zone: 2124 pages used for memmap
[    0.000000]   Normal zone: 0 pages reserved
[    0.000000]   Normal zone: 241664 pages, LIFO batch:31
[    0.000000] [bcm2709_smp_init_cpus] enter (9520->f3003010)
[    0.000000] [bcm2709_smp_init_cpus] ncores=4
[    0.000000] PERCPU: Embedded 13 pages/cpu @b9f63000 s22592 r8192 d22464 u53248
[    0.000000] pcpu-alloc: s22592 r8192 d22464 u53248 alloc=13*4096
[    0.000000] pcpu-alloc: [0] 0 [0] 1 [0] 2 [0] 3
[    0.000000] Built 1 zonelists in Zone order, mobility grouping on.  Total pages: 239540
[    0.000000] Kernel command line: 8250.nr_uarts=0 dma.dmachans=0x7f35 bcm2708_fb.fbwidth=640 bcm2708_fb.fbheight=480 bcm2709.boardrev=0xa02082 bcm2709.serial=0xf0573c6b smsc95xx.macaddr=B8:27:EB:57:3C:6B bcm2708_fb.fbswap=1 bcm2709.uart_clock=48000000 vc_mem.mem_base=0x3dc00000 vc_mem.mem_size=0x3f000000  dwc_otg.lpm_enable=0 console=ttyS0,115200 console=tty1 root=/dev/mmcblk0p7 rootfstype=ext4 elevator=deadline fsck.repair=yes rootwait
[    0.000000] PID hash table entries: 4096 (order: 2, 16384 bytes)
[    0.000000] Dentry cache hash table entries: 131072 (order: 7, 524288 bytes)
[    0.000000] Inode-cache hash table entries: 65536 (order: 6, 262144 bytes)
[    0.000000] Memory: 939088K/966656K available (6340K kernel code, 432K rwdata, 1712K rodata, 480K init, 764K bss, 19376K reserved, 8192K cma-reserved)
[    0.000000] Virtual kernel memory layout:
    vector  : 0xffff0000 - 0xffff1000   (   4 kB)
    fixmap  : 0xffc00000 - 0xfff00000   (3072 kB)
    vmalloc : 0xbb800000 - 0xff800000   (1088 MB)
    lowmem  : 0x80000000 - 0xbb000000   ( 944 MB)
    modules : 0x7f000000 - 0x80000000   (  16 MB)
      .text : 0x80008000 - 0x807e5330   (8053 kB)
      .init : 0x807e6000 - 0x8085e000   ( 480 kB)
      .data : 0x8085e000 - 0x808ca088   ( 433 kB)
       .bss : 0x808cd000 - 0x8098c1ac   ( 765 kB)
[    0.000000] SLUB: HWalign=64, Order=0-3, MinObjects=0, CPUs=4, Nodes=1
[    0.000000] Hierarchical RCU implementation.
[    0.000000]  Build-time adjustment of leaf fanout to 32.
[    0.000000] NR_IRQS:16 nr_irqs:16 16
[    0.000000] Architected cp15 timer(s) running at 19.20MHz (phys).
[    0.000000] clocksource: arch_sys_counter: mask: 0xffffffffffffff max_cycles: 0x46d987e47, max_idle_ns: 440795202767 ns
[    0.000008] sched_clock: 56 bits at 19MHz, resolution 52ns, wraps every 4398046511078ns
[    0.000025] Switching to timer-based delay loop, resolution 52ns
[    0.000293] Console: colour dummy device 80x30
[    0.001342] console [tty1] enabled
[    0.001388] Calibrating delay loop (skipped), value calculated using timer frequency.. 38.40 BogoMIPS (lpj=192000)
[    0.001455] pid_max: default: 32768 minimum: 301
[    0.001785] Mount-cache hash table entries: 2048 (order: 1, 8192 bytes)
[    0.001829] Mountpoint-cache hash table entries: 2048 (order: 1, 8192 bytes)
[    0.002781] Disabling cpuset control group subsystem
[    0.002838] Initializing cgroup subsys io
[    0.002889] Initializing cgroup subsys memory
[    0.002951] Initializing cgroup subsys devices
[    0.002992] Initializing cgroup subsys freezer
[    0.003036] Initializing cgroup subsys net_cls
[    0.003109] CPU: Testing write buffer coherency: ok
[    0.003196] ftrace: allocating 21193 entries in 63 pages
[    0.052327] CPU0: update cpu_capacity 1024
[    0.052392] CPU0: thread -1, cpu 0, socket 0, mpidr 80000000
[    0.052426] [bcm2709_smp_prepare_cpus] enter
[    0.052573] Setting up static identity map for 0x8240 - 0x8274
[    0.054237] [bcm2709_boot_secondary] cpu:1 started (0) 18
[    0.054566] [bcm2709_secondary_init] enter cpu:1
[    0.054608] CPU1: update cpu_capacity 1024
[    0.054615] CPU1: thread -1, cpu 1, socket 0, mpidr 80000001
[    0.054990] [bcm2709_boot_secondary] cpu:2 started (0) 18
[    0.055249] [bcm2709_secondary_init] enter cpu:2
[    0.055270] CPU2: update cpu_capacity 1024
[    0.055276] CPU2: thread -1, cpu 2, socket 0, mpidr 80000002
[    0.055635] [bcm2709_boot_secondary] cpu:3 started (0) 15
[    0.055817] [bcm2709_secondary_init] enter cpu:3
[    0.055837] CPU3: update cpu_capacity 1024
[    0.055843] CPU3: thread -1, cpu 3, socket 0, mpidr 80000003
[    0.055903] Brought up 4 CPUs
[    0.056000] SMP: Total of 4 processors activated (153.60 BogoMIPS).
[    0.056029] CPU: All CPU(s) started in HYP mode.
[    0.056055] CPU: Virtualization extensions available.
[    0.056690] devtmpfs: initialized
[    0.066422] VFP support v0.3: implementor 41 architecture 3 part 40 variant 3 rev 4
[    0.066781] clocksource: jiffies: mask: 0xffffffff max_cycles: 0xffffffff, max_idle_ns: 19112604462750000 ns
[    0.067502] pinctrl core: initialized pinctrl subsystem
[    0.068052] NET: Registered protocol family 16
[    0.073242] DMA: preallocated 4096 KiB pool for atomic coherent allocations
[    0.079886] hw-breakpoint: found 5 (+1 reserved) breakpoint and 4 watchpoint registers.
[    0.079934] hw-breakpoint: maximum watchpoint size is 8 bytes.
[    0.080106] Serial: AMBA PL011 UART driver
[    0.080256] uart-pl011 3f201000.uart: could not find pctldev for node /soc/gpio@7e200000/uart0_pins, deferring probe
[    0.080466] bcm2835-mbox 3f00b880.mailbox: mailbox enabled
[    0.143017] bcm2835-dma 3f007000.dma: DMA legacy API manager at f3007000, dmachans=0x1
[    0.144692] SCSI subsystem initialized
[    0.144887] usbcore: registered new interface driver usbfs
[    0.144997] usbcore: registered new interface driver hub
[    0.145115] usbcore: registered new device driver usb
[    0.151901] raspberrypi-firmware soc:firmware: Attached to firmware from 2016-05-12 12:44
[    0.179158] clocksource: Switched to clocksource arch_sys_counter
[    0.224428] FS-Cache: Loaded
[    0.224743] CacheFiles: Loaded
[    0.236918] NET: Registered protocol family 2
[    0.237795] TCP established hash table entries: 8192 (order: 3, 32768 bytes)
[    0.237934] TCP bind hash table entries: 8192 (order: 4, 65536 bytes)
[    0.238144] TCP: Hash tables configured (established 8192 bind 8192)
[    0.238259] UDP hash table entries: 512 (order: 2, 16384 bytes)
[    0.238327] UDP-Lite hash table entries: 512 (order: 2, 16384 bytes)
[    0.238587] NET: Registered protocol family 1
[    0.238922] RPC: Registered named UNIX socket transport module.
[    0.238954] RPC: Registered udp transport module.
[    0.238982] RPC: Registered tcp transport module.
[    0.239009] RPC: Registered tcp NFSv4.1 backchannel transport module.
[    0.240102] hw perfevents: enabled with armv7_cortex_a7 PMU driver, 7 counters available
[    0.241550] futex hash table entries: 1024 (order: 4, 65536 bytes)
[    0.254690] VFS: Disk quotas dquot_6.6.0
[    0.255016] VFS: Dquot-cache hash table entries: 1024 (order 0, 4096 bytes)
[    0.257433] FS-Cache: Netfs 'nfs' registered for caching
[    0.258320] NFS: Registering the id_resolver key type
[    0.258393] Key type id_resolver registered
[    0.258422] Key type id_legacy registered
[    0.260704] Block layer SCSI generic (bsg) driver version 0.4 loaded (major 252)
[    0.260865] io scheduler noop registered
[    0.260903] io scheduler deadline registered (default)
[    0.260976] io scheduler cfq registered
[    0.263494] BCM2708FB: allocated DMA memory fac00000
[    0.263542] BCM2708FB: allocated DMA channel 0 @ f3007000
[    0.269201] Console: switching to colour frame buffer device 80x30
[    1.087255] bcm2835-rng 3f104000.rng: hwrng registered
[    1.089027] vc-cma: Videocore CMA driver
[    1.090644] vc-cma: vc_cma_base      = 0x00000000
[    1.092211] vc-cma: vc_cma_size      = 0x00000000 (0 MiB)
[    1.093756] vc-cma: vc_cma_initial   = 0x00000000 (0 MiB)
[    1.095499] vc-mem: phys_addr:0x00000000 mem_base=0x3dc00000 mem_size:0x3f000000(1008 MiB)
[    1.113327] brd: module loaded
[    1.123473] loop: module loaded
[    1.125879] vchiq: vchiq_init_state: slot_zero = 0xbac80000, is_master = 0
[    1.128825] Loading iSCSI transport class v2.0-870.
[    1.130989] usbcore: registered new interface driver smsc95xx
[    1.132554] dwc_otg: version 3.00a 10-AUG-2012 (platform bus)
[    1.334343] Core Release: 2.80a
[    1.335833] Setting default values for core params
[    1.337355] Finished setting default values for core params
[    1.539296] Using Buffer DMA mode
[    1.540791] Periodic Transfer Interrupt Enhancement - disabled
[    1.542289] Multiprocessor Interrupt Enhancement - disabled
[    1.543797] OTG VER PARAM: 0, OTG VER FLAG: 0
[    1.545316] Dedicated Tx FIFOs mode
[    1.547129] WARN::dwc_otg_hcd_init:1047: FIQ DMA bounce buffers: virt = 0xbac14000 dma = 0xfac14000 len=9024
[    1.550331] FIQ FSM acceleration enabled for :
Non-periodic Split Transactions
Periodic Split Transactions
High-Speed Isochronous Endpoints
Interrupt/Control Split Transaction hack enabled
[    1.558120] dwc_otg: Microframe scheduler enabled
[    1.558173] WARN::hcd_init_fiq:413: FIQ on core 1 at 0x804459c4
[    1.559838] WARN::hcd_init_fiq:414: FIQ ASM at 0x80445d34 length 36
[    1.561463] WARN::hcd_init_fiq:439: MPHI regs_base at 0xbb932000
[    1.563087] dwc_otg 3f980000.usb: DWC OTG Controller
[    1.564703] dwc_otg 3f980000.usb: new USB bus registered, assigned bus number 1
[    1.567911] dwc_otg 3f980000.usb: irq 62, io mem 0x00000000
[    1.569595] Init: Port Power? op_state=1
[    1.571194] Init: Power Port (0)
[    1.572941] usb usb1: New USB device found, idVendor=1d6b, idProduct=0002
[    1.574569] usb usb1: New USB device strings: Mfr=3, Product=2, SerialNumber=1
[    1.577740] usb usb1: Product: DWC OTG Controller
[    1.579376] usb usb1: Manufacturer: Linux 4.4.9-v7+ dwc_otg_hcd
[    1.581002] usb usb1: SerialNumber: 3f980000.usb
[    1.583377] hub 1-0:1.0: USB hub found
[    1.584982] hub 1-0:1.0: 1 port detected
[    1.587170] dwc_otg: FIQ enabled
[    1.587179] dwc_otg: NAK holdoff enabled
[    1.587188] dwc_otg: FIQ split-transaction FSM enabled
[    1.587218] Module dwc_common_port init
[    1.587450] usbcore: registered new interface driver usb-storage
[    1.589323] mousedev: PS/2 mouse device common for all mice
[    1.591645] bcm2835-cpufreq: min=600000 max=1200000
[    1.593448] sdhci: Secure Digital Host Controller Interface driver
[    1.595023] sdhci: Copyright(c) Pierre Ossman
[    1.596901] sdhost: log_buf @ bac13000 (fac13000)
[    1.669188] mmc0: sdhost-bcm2835 loaded - DMA enabled (>1)
[    1.673050] mmc-bcm2835 3f300000.mmc: mmc_debug:0 mmc_debug2:0
[    1.674658] mmc-bcm2835 3f300000.mmc: DMA channel allocated
[    1.726417] mmc0: host does not support reading read-only switch, assuming write-enable
[    1.729271] sdhci-pltfm: SDHCI platform and OF driver helper
[    1.729664] ledtrig-cpu: registered to indicate activity on CPUs
[    1.729778] hidraw: raw HID events driver (C) Jiri Kosina
[    1.729967] usbcore: registered new interface driver usbhid
[    1.729970] usbhid: USB HID core driver
[    1.730529] Initializing XFRM netlink socket
[    1.730552] NET: Registered protocol family 17
[    1.730675] Key type dns_resolver registered
[    1.731168] Registering SWP/SWPB emulation handler
[    1.732017] registered taskstats version 1
[    1.732203] vc-sm: Videocore shared memory driver
[    1.732211] [vc_sm_connected_init]: start
[    1.739808] [vc_sm_connected_init]: end - returning 0
[    1.741175] 3f201000.uart: ttyAMA0 at MMIO 0x3f201000 (irq = 87, base_baud = 0) is a PL011 rev2
[    1.741562] of_cfs_init
[    1.741637] of_cfs_init: OK
[    1.756633] Waiting for root device /dev/mmcblk0p7...
[    1.758539] mmc0: new high speed SDHC card at address 59b4
[    1.760633] mmcblk0: mmc0:59b4 00000 14.9 GiB
[    1.766201]  mmcblk0: p1 p2 < p5 p6 p7 >
[    1.779262] Indeed it is in host mode hprt0 = 00021501
[    1.788274] mmc1: queuing unknown CIS tuple 0x80 (2 bytes)
[    1.791359] mmc1: queuing unknown CIS tuple 0x80 (3 bytes)
[    1.794336] mmc1: queuing unknown CIS tuple 0x80 (3 bytes)
[    1.798488] mmc1: queuing unknown CIS tuple 0x80 (7 bytes)
[    1.873629] EXT4-fs (mmcblk0p7): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: (null)
[    1.876284] VFS: Mounted root (ext4 filesystem) readonly on device 179:7.
[    1.890722] mmc1: new high speed SDIO card at address 0001
[    1.917677] devtmpfs: mounted
[    1.919846] Freeing unused kernel memory: 480K (807e6000 - 8085e000)
[    1.959197] usb 1-1: new high-speed USB device number 2 using dwc_otg
[    1.960813] Indeed it is in host mode hprt0 = 00001101
[    2.159453] usb 1-1: New USB device found, idVendor=0424, idProduct=9514
[    2.161049] usb 1-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=0, SerialNumber=0
[    2.163353] hub 1-1:1.0: USB hub found
[    2.165004] hub 1-1:1.0: 5 ports detected
[    2.405287] random: systemd urandom read with 67 bits of entropy available
[    2.410829] systemd[1]: systemd 215 running in system mode. (+PAM +AUDIT +SELINUX +IMA +SYSVINIT +LIBCRYPTSETUP +GCRYPT +ACL +XZ -SECCOMP -APPARMOR)
[    2.414431] systemd[1]: Detected architecture 'arm'.
[    2.431926] systemd[1]: Failed to insert module 'ipv6'
[    2.435069] systemd[1]: Set hostname to <raspberrypi>.
[    2.439223] usb 1-1.1: new high-speed USB device number 3 using dwc_otg
[    2.539636] usb 1-1.1: New USB device found, idVendor=0424, idProduct=ec00
[    2.541532] usb 1-1.1: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=0, SerialNumber=0
[    2.548002] smsc95xx v1.0.4
[    2.612399] smsc95xx 1-1.1:1.0 eth0: register 'smsc95xx' at usb-3f980000.usb-1.1, smsc95xx USB 2.0 Ethernet, b8:27:eb:57:3c:6b
[    2.709205] usb 1-1.4: new full-speed USB device number 4 using dwc_otg
[    2.789209] usb 1-1.4: device descriptor read/64, error -32
[    2.993920] systemd[1]: Starting Forward Password Requests to Wall Directory Watch.
[    2.997837] systemd[1]: Started Forward Password Requests to Wall Directory Watch.
[    3.001670] systemd[1]: Starting Remote File Systems (Pre).
[    3.005966] systemd[1]: Reached target Remote File Systems (Pre).
[    3.008048] systemd[1]: Starting Arbitrary Executable File Formats File System Automount Point.
[    3.014508] systemd[1]: Set up automount Arbitrary Executable File Formats File System Automount Point.
[    3.018463] systemd[1]: Starting Encrypted Volumes.
[    3.022807] systemd[1]: Reached target Encrypted Volumes.
[    3.024904] systemd[1]: Starting Swap.
[    3.029134] systemd[1]: Reached target Swap.
[    3.031184] systemd[1]: Expecting device dev-mmcblk0p6.device...
[    3.035393] systemd[1]: Starting Root Slice.
[    3.039781] systemd[1]: Created slice Root Slice.
[    3.041730] systemd[1]: Starting Delayed Shutdown Socket.
[    3.045907] systemd[1]: Listening on Delayed Shutdown Socket.
[    3.047820] systemd[1]: Starting /dev/initctl Compatibility Named Pipe.
[    3.051939] systemd[1]: Listening on /dev/initctl Compatibility Named Pipe.
[    3.053846] systemd[1]: Starting Journal Socket (/dev/log).
[    3.057907] systemd[1]: Listening on Journal Socket (/dev/log).
[    3.059824] systemd[1]: Starting User and Session Slice.
[    3.063848] systemd[1]: Created slice User and Session Slice.
[    3.065670] systemd[1]: Starting udev Control Socket.
[    3.069486] systemd[1]: Listening on udev Control Socket.
[    3.071266] systemd[1]: Starting udev Kernel Socket.
[    3.074998] systemd[1]: Listening on udev Kernel Socket.
[    3.076806] systemd[1]: Starting Journal Socket.
[    3.080750] systemd[1]: Listening on Journal Socket.
[    3.082610] systemd[1]: Starting System Slice.
[    3.086469] systemd[1]: Created slice System Slice.
[    3.088234] systemd[1]: Starting system-systemd\x2dfsck.slice.
[    3.092261] systemd[1]: Created slice system-systemd\x2dfsck.slice.
[    3.094133] systemd[1]: Starting Increase datagram queue length...
[    3.129753] systemd[1]: Starting Restore / save the current clock...
[    3.138983] systemd[1]: Started Create list of required static device nodes for the current kernel.
[    3.143303] systemd[1]: Mounting Debug File System...
[    3.155484] systemd[1]: Started Set Up Additional Binary Formats.
[    3.157449] systemd[1]: Mounted Huge Pages File System.
[    3.181074] systemd[1]: Starting Load Kernel Modules...
[    3.187944] systemd[1]: Starting Create Static Device Nodes in /dev...
[    3.194819] systemd[1]: Starting udev Coldplug all Devices...
[    3.201652] systemd[1]: Mounting POSIX Message Queue File System...
[    3.208574] systemd[1]: Starting system-autologin.slice.
[    3.213546] systemd[1]: Created slice system-autologin.slice.
[    3.216029] systemd[1]: Starting File System Check on Root Device...
[    3.223228] systemd[1]: Starting Slices.
[    3.227817] systemd[1]: Reached target Slices.
[    3.240939] systemd[1]: Started Increase datagram queue length.
[    3.312192] systemd[1]: Mounted Debug File System.
[    3.315187] systemd[1]: systemd-modules-load.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
[    3.324332] systemd[1]: Failed to start Load Kernel Modules.
[    3.326310] systemd[1]: Unit systemd-modules-load.service entered failed state.
[    3.403660] systemd[1]: Started Restore / save the current clock.
[    3.409237] systemd[1]: Started Create Static Device Nodes in /dev.
[    3.414591] systemd[1]: Mounted POSIX Message Queue File System.
[    3.419136] systemd[1]: Time has been changed
[    3.450428] systemd[1]: Started File System Check on Root Device.
[    3.455740] systemd[1]: Started udev Coldplug all Devices.
[    3.578289] systemd[1]: Starting udev Kernel Device Manager...
[    3.620054] systemd[1]: Mounting Configuration File System...
[    3.626665] systemd[1]: Starting Apply Kernel Variables...
[    3.634620] systemd[1]: Mounted FUSE Control File System.
[    3.636960] systemd[1]: Starting Syslog Socket.
[    3.641388] systemd-udevd[128]: starting version 215
[    3.643648] systemd[1]: Listening on Syslog Socket.
[    3.645832] systemd[1]: Starting Journal Service...
[    3.654896] systemd[1]: Started Journal Service.
[    4.391360] EXT4-fs (mmcblk0p7): re-mounted. Opts: (null)
[    4.769824] systemd-journald[132]: Received request to flush runtime journal from PID 1
[    4.899238] usb 1-1.4: new high-speed USB device number 5 using dwc_otg
[    5.070198] usb 1-1.4: New USB device found, idVendor=3538, idProduct=0902
[    5.071149] usb 1-1.4: New USB device strings: Mfr=2, Product=3, SerialNumber=1
[    5.072921] usb 1-1.4: Product: AS2105
[    5.073827] usb 1-1.4: Manufacturer: ASMedia
[    5.074733] usb 1-1.4: SerialNumber: 0123456789ABCDEF
[    5.077807] usb-storage 1-1.4:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[    5.079194] scsi host0: usb-storage 1-1.4:1.0
[    5.770462] smsc95xx 1-1.1:1.0 eth0: hardware isn't capable of remote wakeup
[    6.080329] scsi 0:0:0:0: Direct-Access     TOSHIBA  MK5059GSXP       GN00 PQ: 0 ANSI: 0
[    6.085301] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] 976773168 512-byte logical blocks: (500 GB/466 GiB)
[    6.087600] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Write Protect is off
[    6.088563] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Mode Sense: 23 00 00 00
[    6.088856] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] No Caching mode page found
[    6.089815] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Assuming drive cache: write through
[    6.113668]  sda: sda1
[    6.115790] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Attached SCSI disk
[    7.318246] smsc95xx 1-1.1:1.0 eth0: link up, 100Mbps, full-duplex, lpa 0x45E1
[    8.428614] random: nonblocking pool is initialized
[   67.825872] uart-pl011 3f201000.uart: no DMA platform data
[   68.170021] Adding 102396k swap on /var/swap.  Priority:-1 extents:4 across:823292k SSFS
[   88.343113] EXT4-fs (sda1): mounting ext3 file system using the ext4 subsystem
[   88.751763] EXT4-fs (sda1): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: (null)
[   88.879104] EXT4-fs (mmcblk0p5): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: (null)
```

(Pi was connected wirelessly to router, and there was ethernet cable from pi to my smarttv - smarttv whas using pi's access to internet)

Comment: There seems to be no mention of any wifi devices in `dmesg`... what's the result of running `dpkg --get-selections | grep firmware`?  (You might be missing `firmware-brcm80211`.)

Answer (score 1):

Presumably something went wrong during an upgrade Run `sudo apt-get update; sudo apt-get install --reinstall raspberrypi-bootloader raspberrypi-kernel`
will put it back to the latest supported kernel/bootcode.

NOTE This may take a while - **BE PATIENT** until it finishes.

Comment: tried but it did not help